# Bluetooth mouse/keyboard emulation

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, mouse, hid, emulation

I'm having a hard time finding a software that would emulates a Bluetooth keyboard (and/or mouse) that follows HID standard. 
I've already found one, but I couldn't get it working: http://mulliner.org/bluetooth/xkbdbthid.php

I'm only interested in a solution that uses HID standard so that other machines can immediately recognize the soft as Bluetooth hid device, without the need of any pre-installed softwares. (Running under Windows or Linux if possible.)

Would it be possible to write a code in java to emulate Bluetooth hid devices?

Any help would be very appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It's been a while since you asked the question, but I'm going to add this answer anyway, it may help you or someone else.

I'm also interested in Bluetooth HID emulation, ideally from within some Java/Android code. However, I came across this Python-based script/project:

http://code.google.com/p/hidemulator

I've not tried this code myself, but from what I can see, the script is reasonably easy to follow. It currently only supports the PS3's six-axis controller, but maybe you (or I, if I ever get the time) could adapt the Nokia project's Keyboard and Mouse routines into the Python script (or convert it to Java/Groovy, which is my ultimate goal ;-) ).

Cheers

Rich

Answer (score 1):

It's not you are searching for but for Android devices.

AndroHid
http://code.google.com/p/androhid/

You need rooted device.
Unfortunately it doesn't work on my Nexus S - Cyanogen 9

Answer (score 1):

btkbdd does this for Linux with Bluez. See: https://github.com/lkundrak/virtkbd/blob/master/btkbdd.pod

Comment: Hi i installed btkbdd and evmuxd but cannot configure it :(. Your web site seams not working and I cannot able to create issue on github as well. So can you help me?

Comment: It says "Could not grab keyboard for exclusive use: Inappropriate ioctl for device"

Comment: It seems to have moved to [lkundrak/btkbdd](https://github.com/lkundrak/btkbdd/blob/47cc7916e13b28eeb89dcfe978162167adecbc8c/btkbdd/btkbdd.pod)?